# Selecting multiple items in Jlist

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist

**I am trying to be able to select multiple items at a time** and add them to my table but when I attempt at doing so, I am getting an array out of bounds exception. I think this is due to my listToArr method because it allows me to select one item at a time just fine without any errors. I made the listToArr method because insertRow() in a table model requires an int for the first parameter and an Object[] or Vector for the second parameter.

I also would love to know how to make the highlighted selected items become unhighlighted after my select button is pressed.

```
private void populateTable(JList<String> items){           
        DefaultTableModel t = (DefaultTableModel) selectedItemsTable.getModel();
        t.insertRow(t.getRowCount()-1, listToArr(items));
        selectedItemsTable.setModel(t);     
}

private Object[] listToArr(JList<String> l){
    Object[] o = new Object[l.getComponentCount()];
    int i=0;
    for(Object value : l.getSelectedValuesList()){
        o[i] = (Object) value;
        i++;
    }
    return o;
}

private void SelectNeedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    populateTable(needsList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> and an Object[] or Vector for the second parameter.

The second parameter is an Array containing data for each column in the row. When you only select a single item this means you only have a single column in the table.

If you select 3 items then it means you will have 3 columns in the table.

I suspect you created your table with only a single column. This means you need to iterate through the List of selected items and add an Array containing each item separately , which will give you 3 rows with only a single column.

> because insertRow() in a table model requires an int for the first parameter

You can just use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel`. It will add the row to the end of the table model.

```
//selectedItemsTable.setModel(t); // get rid of this
```

There is no need to reset the model. The point of using a model is that it will notify the view (JTable) when the data is changed.